# import module from subfolder to different subfolder in python3x

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following dir structure for my project:

```
Project
 |
 +-- __init__.py
 |
 +-- run.py
 |    
 +-- dir1
 |  | 
 |  +-- __init__.py 
 |  +-- module1.py
 |    
 +-- dir2
 |  | 
 |  +-- __init__.py 
 |  +-- module2.py
```

I want to import some functions that are defined in module1 into module2. And ultimately fucntions from module2 are imported into `run.py` which is the main script.

I tried put the below line in `module2.py`:

```py
from ..module1 import something
```

then when i try doing :

```sh
python3 run.py
```

or

```sh
python3 -m run.py
```

I get this error:

```sh
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

**All the `__init__.py` files are empty**

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this

```
from dir1.module1 import your_function
from dir2.module2 import your_second_function
```

this should do the job!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `PYTHONPATH` to your root project folder (in you example: `Project`).
This will ensure that wherever you start python script and wherever your modules are placed they will be accessible as relative path from the `PYTHONPATH` folder.

Another way is to add you project root to `sys.path` eg `sys.path.insert(0, 'path_to_root')` but this requires to do this in all your scripts before importing any of your modules.

Once set you can do from any of your script (even if they are not in a subfolder of `Project`)

```
from dir1.module1 import *
```